# mongodb mapreduce - missing data

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Here are my Map, Reduce and finalize functions. There are 4 records matching the key and the result comes correctly when mapreduce is invoked with fewer data (100s) but constanly getting the count as 2 when mapreduce is invoked with more data (few 1000s). I checked the Reduce function and to me it seems to be correct even if it is internally being invoked multiple times for larger data. This is getting weird and I've spend long hours and still couldn't get it right.

```
var map1 = function(){
    var mapPosCnt = 0, mapPosSum = 0, mapZeroCnt = 0;
    if (isNumber(this.val1)){
        if(this.val1.toPrecision(10)  > 0.0000000000){
            mapPosCnt = 1;
            mapPosSum = this.val1;
        }else{
            mapZeroCnt = 1;
        }
    }else{
        mapPosCnt = 0, mapPosSum = 0, mapZeroCnt = 0;
    }
    emit({key1: this.key1, key2: this.key2+'', val1: 'val1'}
        ,{key1: this.key1, key2: this.key2+'', posCnt: mapPosCnt, posSum: mapPosSum, posAvg: 0, zeroCnt: mapZeroCnt, val1: this.val1});
}
var reduce1 = function(key, values){
    var retval = {key1: key.CE, key2: key.key2, posCnt: 0, posSum: 0, posAvg: 0, zeroCnt: 0, val1: 0};
    values.forEach(function(value){
        if (isNumber(value.val1)){
            if(value.val1.toPrecision(10)  > 0.0000000000){
                retval.posCnt += 1;
                retval.posSum += value.val1;
            }else{
                retval.zeroCnt += 1;
            }
        }
    })
    return retval;
}
var finalize1 = function(key, value){
    value.key2 = value.key2.toString();
    if(value.posCnt > 0){
        value.posSum = Math.round(value.posSum * Math.pow(10, 6)) / Math.pow(10, 6);
        value.posAvg = Math.round((value.posSum/value.posCnt) * Math.pow(10, 6)) / Math.pow(10, 6);
    }
    return value;
}
collection1.mapReduce(map1, reduce1, {out: {merge: 'collection2'}, finalize: finalize1}, function(err, collection){});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the docs to test it I'm guessing a bit, but I can see a couple issues:

1. The emitted/reduced values shouldn't include the key fields.  So your emitted value should look like this instead:  `{ posCnt: mapPosCnt, posSum: mapPosSum, zeroCnt: mapZeroCnt }`
2. The reduce function shouldn't try to re-apply the emit logic like you're doing, rather it should be aggregating the values with the same key by summing their values.

So `reduce1` should look like:

```js
var reduce1 = function(key, values){
    var retval = { posCnt: 0, posSum: 0, zeroCnt: 0 };
    values.forEach(function(value){
        retval.posCnt += value.posCnt;
        retval.posSum += value.posSum;
        retval.zeroCnt += value.zeroCnt;
    });
    return retval;
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot Johnny; fixing the 2 issues that you mentioned solved the randomly missing data issue that i was facing. Sorry for the late response as I was pulled into different tasks the whole week and just worked on this.